# Global variable inside class and function PHP

Tags: php, function, global

I'm having trouble with reading variable defined in one function in another function.
I have:

```
global $a;
class test{
    function aa($somevar){
        switch ($myvar){
        case 'value':
            global $a;
            $a = 15;
            break;
        }
    }
    function bb(){
        global $a;
        echo $a;
    }
}

$foo = new test();
$ccc = $foo->bb();

var_dump($ccc);
```

I get dump result NULL.
Thanx

Comment: But you nowhere assign value to `$aa`.

Comment: No value is ever being assigned to $a anywhere wthin the flow of this code; bb() returns nothing to assign to $ccc; aa() switches on a non-existent variable; and you should avoid using global wherever possible anyway

Comment: Why are you trying to use a global variable instead of a class member?

Comment: $a is assigned inside switch $a = 15; and this aa function can accept only one parameter $somevar and nothing else

Comment: @user1756097 no you don't call the method where switch is

Comment: is there a way to get switch result in funciton bb?

Comment: modify bb() so that it calls $this->aa(), but fix your bl***y example so it at least makes some sense

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$a` should be [a property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) inside the class

Answer (score 0):

At no point in your code do you assign a value to `$a`.

The only assignment to `$a` is in the `test->aa` method, which uses inconsistent variables and therefore even if called will never assign to `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

You never run `test->aa()` to assign a value to `a`.

```
$foo = new test();
$foo->aa();
$ccc = $foo->bb();
```

In this case `$ccc` will still be null because you are echoing `$a` in `$foo->bb()` instead of returning it.

```
function bb() {
  global $a;
  return $a;
}
```

I would also stay away from globals and pass the variable $a on construct of the class.  For example:

```
class test {
    public $a;

    function __construct($a = null) {
      // pass initial var to $a if you want
      $this->a = $a;
    }

   function aa($somevar) {
      // reassign $a
      $this->a = $somevar;
   }
}

$foo = new test();
$foo->aa(5);
// or just $foo = new test(5);
var_dump($foo->a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class test
{
    public $a;
    function aa($somevar)
    {
        switch ($myvar)
        {
         case 'value':
         $this->a = 15;
         break;
        }
    }
    function bb()
    {        
        return $this->a;
    }
}

$foo = new test();
$ccc = $foo->bb();

var_dump($ccc);
```

UPDATED:

```
<?php
class test
{
    var $a;
    function aa($somevar)
    {
        switch ($somevar)
        {
         case 'value':
         $this->a = 15;
         break;
        }
    }
    function bb()
    {        
        return $this->a;
    }
}

$foo = new test();
$foo->aa('value');
$ccc = $foo->bb();

var_dump($ccc);
?>
```

Comment: +1 for removing global variables.  -2 for not solving initial problem ($ccc still is null). `test->bb` must return `test->a`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code try this..

```
<?php
 global $a;
  class test{

    function aa($somevar){
       switch ($somevar){
        case 'value':
            global $a;
            $a = 15;
            break;
        }
    }

function bb(){
    global $a;
    echo $a;
    return $a;
}
}

$foo = new test();
$foo->aa('value');
$ccc = $foo->bb();

var_dump($ccc);


?>
```

Comment: Not possible because variable in function and switch are not the same